# Building my own themeroller

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

My company is starting to get into a lot of web projects (web applications, not web sites) and one of the demands is that all the web apps should be theme-able.

I was thinking about building an internal themeroller for the company, but i couldn't find any resource on how to go about such a project.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Where can i find resources on the subject, at least to get me started?
2. Is it doable in a reasonable time (6-12 months, 1-2 developers)?
3. Any pointer you could give me would be appreciated

I'm proficient with Java,JS,PHP.

Comment: Well if your styling is handled by the browser with CSS - all you have to do is swap out those files to give a totally different theme. I guess it all boils down to correct and generic use of class names and structure.

Comment: correct, but we want to enable developers to have a set of custom predefined classes and styles to start with, and we want it to be standardized

Comment: What about taking a look at how [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) handles their separation of layout from style? IMO they've done a pretty good job and it would be a great starting point.

Comment: Specifically, you should definitely look at [this page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html#variables). It does exactly what you are talking about - if I understood you correctly..

Comment: saw that but it has a couple of caveats: 1. It requires the use of css LESS, or any other pre-processor (not bad but we rather not force nothing). 2. We want something that a designer (not a developer) can sit and dabble with. 3.we might want customers to be able to use it